# Вывести отдельно записи за каждый день

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в следующем: пытаюсь создать временную линию событий, в которой события группируются по дням. Т.е. сначала выводится плашка с датой (`$event_data`), а ниже идут события, произошедшие в этот день. НО! Плашка с датой выводится перед каждым событием. Понимаю, что это из-за:

```
<li class='time-label'>
    <span class='bg-red'>
        ".$event_data."
    </span>
</li>
```

Но никак не могу понять, как разграничить вывод плашки с датой и событий. Код:

```
<? require ('plugins/rusDate.php');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res3)) {
        $event_data = rus_date("j M Y", strtotime($row['4']));
        $event_time = rus_date("H:i", strtotime($row['4']));
        $event_gamename = $row['2'];
        $event_giveaway_type = $row['1'];
        $event_end = rus_date("j M Y H:i", strtotime($row['5']));
        echo "<li class='time-label'>
                <span class='bg-red'>
                    ".$event_data."
                </span>
              </li>
              <!-- timeline item -->
              <li>
                 <i class='fa fa-plus bg-blue'></i>
                     <div class='timeline-item'>
                        <span class='time'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> ".$event_time."</span>
                        <h3 class='timeline-header'><a href='#'></a> ".$event_gamename."</h3>
                        <div class='timeline-body'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='timeline-footer'>
                          <a class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Перейти</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
              </li>
              <!-- END timeline item -->";
}
?>
```

Comment: Используйте if для проверкки сменился ли день, если да, то выведите новый день

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как пример:

```html
<? require ('plugins/rusDate.php');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res3)) {
        $event_data = rus_date("j M Y", strtotime($row['4']));
        $event_time = rus_date("H:i", strtotime($row['4']));
        $event_gamename = $row['2'];
        $event_giveaway_type = $row['1'];
        $event_end = rus_date("j M Y H:i", strtotime($row['5']));
        
        if ($event_data != $event_data_temp){
        
          $event_data_temp = $event_data;
          $text = "<span class='bg-red'>".$event_data."</span>";
          
        } else {
        
          $text = "";
          
        }
        
        
        echo "<li class='time-label'>
                $text
              </li>
              <!-- timeline item -->
              <li>
                 <i class='fa fa-plus bg-blue'></i>
                     <div class='timeline-item'>
                        <span class='time'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> ".$event_time."</span>
                        <h3 class='timeline-header'><a href='#'></a> ".$event_gamename."</h3>
                        <div class='timeline-body'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='timeline-footer'>
                          <a class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Перейти</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
              </li>
              <!-- END timeline item -->";
}
?>
```